# Calculate Current

Tags: current, current-measurement

how to i calculate current( Before Resistance ) from these parameters

- Voltage before Resistance
- Voltage after resistance
- Resistor Value
- Current After Resistance

Comment: Some links to help you improve your questions. [English Capitalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_in_English); [How to Ask a Good Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: What do you mean by current(Before Resistance)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question leaves me puzzled, because I cannot guess what kind of circuit it relates to.

But let's assume you write about a simple loop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0UJ00.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then your parameters are:

- Voltage before resistance = V1 (probably)
- Voltage after resistance = V3
- Resistance = R1 = 100 Ω (this example)
- Current after resistance = Current before resistance = (V1-V3)/R1

The latter is due to Kirchhoffs law.

But maybe you think of an entirely different schematic? We can only guess.